# Transform/convert shape into line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, transform, clipping-mask

I want to create a clipping mask (Object > Clipping Mask) with a rounded rectangle shape above an image. But when I do it, rounded edges get angled (straight, without rounds).

How to transform that shape into a line (line object), so that, when I create a clipping mask, the rounded edges will be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lock in styles like rounded corners by Expanding.

Once expanded your shape will truly have round corners which can be used to clip.

So, in short, expand it.